# Django - Customising the display of FormSet objects?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-forms

I have a formset with can_delete set, i.e. I want to allow people to be able to delete the objects. I want to customise the layout of each of the forms, like this: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#customizing-the-form-template . I can add the fields for each form with `{{ form.name_of_field }}`, etc. However I'm not sure what to put (in the template) for the 'delete' checkbox. This field comes up normally when you go `{{ form.as_ul }}`.

What's the value for the delete field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
{{ form.DELETE }}
```